# Always got 403 response code when check all link with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I made script for checking all link in one page, but all of the link always give  403 response code, it will opened normally with browser but if checking it by getting response code using selenium java always give 403(Forbidden), i also bring all cookies but it doesn't work, if anyone have solution please let me know.
Thanks in advance.
this is my code to store all cookie and bring them in all link response check

```js
private int getHttpResponseStatusCode(String webPageUrl) {
  int ret = -1;
  try {
    if (webPageUrl != null && !"".equals(webPageUrl.trim())) {
      URL urlObj = new URL(webPageUrl.trim());
      HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
      Set <Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
      String cookieString = "";
      for (Cookie cookie: cookies) {
        cookieString += cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + ";";
      }
      httpConn.addRequestProperty("Cookies", cookieString);
      httpConn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
      httpConn.connect();
      ret = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    System.out.println("Http Status Code : " + ret + " , Url : " + webPageUrl);
    return ret;
  }
};
```

this is how i get all the link from the page

```js
private List <String> parseOutAllUrlLinksInWebPage(String webPageUrl) {
  List <String> retList = new ArrayList <String> ();
  if (webPageUrl != null && !"".equals(webPageUrl.trim())) {
    /* Get current page belongs domain. */
    String urlDomain = this.getPageBelongDomain(webPageUrl);
    /* First parse out all a tag href urls. */
    By byUrlLink = By.tagName("a");
    List <WebElement> aLinkList = driver.findElements(byUrlLink);
    if (aLinkList != null) {
      int aLinkSize = aLinkList.size();
      for (int i = 0; i <aLinkSize; i++) {
        WebElement aLink = aLinkList.get(i);
        String href = aLink.getAttribute("href");

        if (href != null && !"".equals(href.trim())) {
          /* Only return same domain page url. */
          if (href.toLowerCase().startsWith("http://" + urlDomain) || href.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://" + urlDomain)) {
            retList.add(href);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    /* Second parse out all img tag src urls. */
    By byImg = By.tagName("img");
    List <WebElement> imgList = driver.findElements(byImg);

    if (imgList != null) {
      int imgSize = imgList.size();
      for (int i = 0; i <imgSize; i++) {
        WebElement imgElement = imgList.get(i);
        String src = imgElement.getAttribute("src");

        if (src != null && !"".equals(src.trim())) {
          /* Only return same domain page url. */
          if (src.toLowerCase().startsWith("http://" + urlDomain) || src.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://" + urlDomain)) {
            retList.add(src);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  System.out.println("Parse out url completed successfully.");
  return retList;
};
```

Comment: Perhaps your server is blocking HEAD requests - is it your server? Also where is the JavaScript? I removed the tag

Comment: same result using HEAD or GET, this is company website, company server, no javascript sorry it's wrong tag

Comment: So perhaps all except POST is disallowed

Comment: yes but always got 403 response, using HEAD or GET

Comment: So try POST....

Comment: same result, 403

Comment: Have a read of this and make sure your URL is valid https://www.lifewire.com/403-forbidden-error-explained-2617989

Comment: well all link are generated automatically, so the perception URL is valid, but when i want to get response code using selenium it will give 403 code.

Comment: Please search for [selenium 403](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bselenium%5D+403)